# When looking at a mutual fund, how can you tell if it is a traditional fund or an ETF?

Tags: mutual-funds, financial-literacy, etf

From [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/71225/what-is-a-mutual-fund/71227?noredirect=1#comment113687_71227)  question here I understand what a mutual fund is. 
From the best answer selected, I can understand what a mutual fund is.

Having read [this](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/758/what-are-the-important-differences-between-mutual-funds-and-exchange-traded-fund), I can understand the definition of a ETF.

Looking at something like the  JP Morgan Emerging Markets Equity Fund which is a mutual fund. 
Is this also an ETF?

Can a mutual fund also be an ETF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the important differences between mutual funds and Exchange Traded Funds (ETFs)?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/758/what-are-the-important-differences-between-mutual-funds-and-exchange-traded-fund)

Comment: I do not consider this question a duplicate. The other question discusses the differences on how they work. This question shows how to identify whether or not a particular fund is an ETF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Exchange-Traded Fund (ETF) is a special type of mutual fund that is traded on the stock exchange like a stock.  To invest, you buy it through a stock broker, just as you would if you were buying an individual stock.

When looking at a mutual fund based in the U.S., the easiest way to tell whether or not it is an ETF is by looking at the ticker symbol.  Traditional mutual funds have ticker symbols that end in "X", and ETFs have ticker symbols that do not end in "X".

The [JPMorgan Emerging Markets Equity Fund](https://am.jpmorgan.com/us/en/asset-management/gim/adv/products/d/jpmorgan-emerging-markets-equity-fund-a-4812a0607), with ticker symbol JFAMX, is a traditional mutual fund, not an ETF.  [JPMorgan does have ETFs](https://am.jpmorgan.com/us/en/asset-management/gim/adv/fund-explorer/exchange-fund/all/all); the [JPMorgan Diversified Return Emerging Markets Equity ETF](https://am.jpmorgan.com/us/en/asset-management/gim/adv/products/d/jpmorgan-diversified-return-emerging-markets-equity-etf-etf-shares-46641q308), with ticker symbol JPEM, is an example.  This ETF invests in similar stocks as JFAMX; however, because it is an index-based fund instead of an actively managed fund, it has lower fees.

If you aren't sure about the ticker symbol, the advertising/prospectus of any ETF should clearly state that it is an ETF.  (In the example of JPEM above, they put "ETF" right in the fund name.)  If you don't see ETF mentioned, it is most likely a traditional mutual fund.

Another way to tell is by looking at the "investment minimums" of the fund.  [JFAMX has a minimum initial investment](https://am.jpmorgan.com/us/en/asset-management/gim/adv/products/d/jpmorgan-emerging-markets-equity-fund-a-4812a0607##Fees) of $1000.  ETFs, however, do not have an investment minimum listed; because it is traded like a stock, you simply buy whole shares at whatever the current share price is.  So if you look at the ["Fees and Investment Minimums" section of the JPEM page](https://am.jpmorgan.com/us/en/asset-management/gim/adv/products/d/jpmorgan-diversified-return-emerging-markets-equity-etf-etf-shares-46641q308##FeesandInvestmentMinimums), you'll see the fees listed, but not any investment minimums.