# Indian equivalent of Vanguard S&P 500

Tags: india, mutual-funds, vanguard

I was going through the article - [Warren Buffett wins $1M bet made a decade ago that the S&P 500 stock index would outperform hedge funds](http://www.aei.org/publication/warren-buffett-wins-1m-bet-made-a-decade-ago-that-the-sp-500-stock-index-would-outperform-hedge-funds/)

The name Vanguard is pretty popular even among non US citizens regarding their low cost fees and index funds.

I wanted to know whether India also has a company similar to Vanguard which offers low cost index funds.

Also, when they mean SP500 fund - it means that fund which invests in the top 500 companies in the SP Index, is my understanding correct?

Edit: It might be against the rules to recommend products or service, so in that case how do I find out myself? What are the steps to figuring out the equivalent fund?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, when they mean SP500 fund - it means that fund which invests in the top 500 companies in the SP Index, is my understanding correct?

Yes that is right. In reality they may not be able to invest in all 500 companies in same proportion, but is reflective of the composition.

> I wanted to know whether India also has a company similar to Vanguard which offers low cost index funds.

Almost all mutual fund companies offer a NIFTY index fund, both as mutual fund as well as ETF. You can search for index fund and see the total assets to find out which is bigger compared to others.

Comment: what is the difference between a mutual fund and an ETF?

Comment: @bluefalcon Read this question and if you still have doubts, raise specific question. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/758/what-are-the-important-differences-between-mutual-funds-and-exchange-traded-fund/66193#66193